# QGIS DB manager Import layer/file tool won't allow me to choose "Append data to table"

Tags: qgis, postgis

I want to append some data to a layer in my PostGIS DB using a shapefile, but when I use the Import layer/file tool in QGIS, it doesn't allow me to choose the append option.  Why is this and how do I get it to allow me to append?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem goes for me with the DB manager in QGIS - Append not available.

But it is pretty stright forward in pgAdmin III with the plugin 'PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager'.

Be sure to set Mode to Append, SRID, Table name to name of table to append to. Also in
Import Options disable 'Create spatial index automatically after load'.

[image: PostGIS shapefile importer]

Comment: You are right that this can be done through the PostGIS shapfile importer. I more just want to know why it isn't working in QGIS, because it would be nice to not have to go from one to the other.  It should just work in QGIS, but apparently some condition is not being met to allow that option to be available, but there is no documentation which states what WILL make that option available.

Comment: @Jakob how can I set Append mode in postgresql? I could not found in pgadmin III

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this has not been implemented yet. The latest information I could find was [on the mailing list in July 2013](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Dbmanager-import-several-shapefiles-into-a-single-postgis-layer-append-td5065007.html).

Comment: thanks @underdark. How can I learn when implemented? Is there a QGIS page about new features?

Comment: Check if there is an existing feature request on http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues. If there is one, you can follow it to get updates. If there is none yet, you can open a request and you will get updates by mail. For guidance check http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#bugs-features-and-issues

Comment: Currently, there is an existing ticket: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10569